# How to view / debug Javascript when using Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 does a great job of letting me debug directly in TypeScript and a lot of the time this is extremely helpful.  That said, there are times when I REALLY need to debug the underlying Javascript and I can't see how to do it.  Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to let me debug in Javascript?

Between the problem with "this" really being "_this" and screwing up the debugger and async / away functions generating very different underlying code it becomes critical to be able to access the Javascript to debug.

Comment: `there are times when I REALLY need to debug the underlying Javascript` <= Like when? Also just use the browser's debugging tools if you want to do that.

Comment: As I noted..  Visual Studio does NOT display values requiring "this" correctly.  More specifically => screws up Visual Studios ability to access "this" as the code generated is using "_this".

Comment: That is not VS but that is how the arrow functions capture `this` when they are transpiled to javascript. Again, you can use the browser's debugging tools which I find preferable over VS when it comes to debugging script.

Comment: Its a bug that needs a work around.

Comment: Then use the browser's debugging tools. All major browsers have a debugger that you can step, do breakpoints, see the source, etc. In the worst case scenario, you need to disable sourcemaps. But to be honest, I've never ran into that situation, nor have ran into issues with transpilation that needed that kind of inspection.

Answer (score 2):

> it becomes critical to be able to access the Javascript to debug.

Disable sourcemaps.

- In your debugger e.g. chrome options
- In your tsconfig `sourceMap: false`
- In your webpack config `devtool : 'none'`
- Anywhere else you might have configured it